# Login error for user "xxxxx", Visual Studio, SQL Server (error 18456 state 10)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, authentication

I'm testing my app who connects to my DB and starts executing SQL sentences. After a few thousand querys I get the following error from Visual Studio: "Login error for user xxxxx" and in different points of the code.

The SQL Server's authentication is "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".

Any help on this,

Thanks.

Comment: There should be additional information in the Exception object returned with the error.  Post that here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 then maybe [FIX: Error message when you try to use a SQL Server authenticated login to log on to an instance of SQL Server 2005: "Logon error: 18456"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925744) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think sr.u tries to say that the error occurs at various points of the code, after a number, maybe many successful executions.

So I'd rather suspect that he or she just opens a new connection for every SQL command and simply forgets to close it. Or something like this.

Comment: I have reviewed it, and I closed everything.

Comment: Did you look at the activity monitor of the SQL server? What does it show? I mean during the execution of your code.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've fixed it by running half of the SQL statements with another (identical) connection.